# ruby-on-rails - custom method and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I have a program with users and projects (many to many relation). I would like to create my own methods: to delete all projects from specific user and to delete specific project from specific user, but I can't handle that. There is (quiet big) possibility I don't understand routes.

Below I insert code to delete all project from specific user.

In my user_controller.rb I have:

```
def delete_projects_from_user
    @user.projects.delete_all
end
```

In show.html.erb link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete all projects', @user, method: :delete_projects_from_user, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And in routes I tried among others this two option:

```
resources :users do
    get 'delete_projects_from_user', on: :member
end
```

or

```
post '/users/:id', to: 'users#delete_projects_from_user', as: :delete_projects_from_user
```

First option trows: "No route matches [POST] "/users/(id)"
Second option just do nothing.

I will be grateful for prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic format:

```
<%= link_to 'DISPLAY TEXT', YOUR_ROUTE_path(@object), method:
 :HTTP_METHOD, data: { Additional html params } %>
```

Here is the solution:

`<%= link_to 'Remove All Projects', delete_projects_from_user_path(@user), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Then in your method:

```
 def delete_projects_from_user
   user = user.find(params[:id])
   user.projects.delete_all
   redirect_to :back #if nothing to render  
 end
```

I'm sure this may help you.

Comment: I've got "undefined method `delete_projects_from_user'"

Comment: @Weronika try this `delete_projects_from_user_path(@user)` else check in `rake routes` you will get all routes in that routes add `_path` at the end and try. `<%= link_to 'Remove All Projects', delete_projects_from_user_path(@user), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Comment: Error disapeared but now nothing happens.

Comment: check the controller method is defined properly or not?

Comment: I tried two version - primary and yours. `class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]    def delete_projects_from_user
    @user.projects.delete_all
  end`

Comment: check the `@user.projects` giving all projects are not. Already projects are deleted means nothing going to happen for empty results.

Comment: Okey, I've got very stupid mistake. When I put `@user.projects.delete_all` => undefined method `projects`, but if I put your version there is no method `find`

Comment: I found solution! `@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.projects.delete_all` Thanks so much for  help!

Comment: Maybe can you help me with one other connected thing - I have to make few routes like that because I have tasks in the same relation as project. How can I do that?

Comment: share the repo to me and give some background regarding that.

Comment: Sorry, I just see I wrote but didn't add comment. Thanks, I comprehended that in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

For this

```
def delete_projects_from_user
  @user.projects.delete_all
end
```

You better user .destroy_all to make sure this object and all of it's associated items are destroyed as well

.delete_all only delete the object and it leaves the associated entries on the DB

and As for this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete all projects', @user, method: :delete_projects_from_user, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

In your route you defined your route as post so it should be

```
method: :post
```

to be like this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete all projects', @user, method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And here you haven't added the route correctly, it should be like this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete all projects', YOUR_ROUTE_path(@user), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

While it's recommended to define this route like this

```
delete '/users/:id', to: 'users#delete_projects_from_user', as: :delete_projects_from_user
```

As for the 2nd option, you can use collection as well

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    delete 'user/:id', to: 'users#delete_projects_from_user', as: :delete_projects_from_user
  end
end
```

and modify the link to be

```
<%= link_to 'Delete all projects', delete_projects_from_user(@user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Both options are fine, and the 2nd one with delete is the recommended one

Comment: It deletes user but I would like to delete all association between specific user and projects, not the objects.

Comment: Using .destroy_all should delete the object and all of it's associations